# Trouble running async functions in background threads (concurrency)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, concurrency

I'm having trouble making async functions run in background threads (to prevent blocking the main thread).

Below is a method that takes about 5 seconds to run.
From what I've learned, it seemed like making the function `async` and marking it with `await` on function call would be enough. But it doesn't work as intended and still freezes up the UI.

**EDIT**
Since it's stated that Swift 5.5 concurrency can replace DispatchQueue, I am trying to find a way to do this with only Async/Await.

**EDIT_2**
I did try removing the @MainActor wrapper, but it still seem to run on the main thread.

### NumberManager.swift

```
@MainActor class NumberManager: ObservableObject {
@Published var numbers: [Double]?    

func generateNumbers() async  {

        var numbers = [Double]()
        numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
        self.numbers = numbers
    // takes about 5 seconds to run...
} }
```

### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject private var numberManager = NumberManager()

var body: some View{
    TabView{
        VStack{
            DetailView(text: isNumbersValid ? "First number is: \(numberManager.numbers![0])" : nil)
                .onAppear() {
                    Task {
                        // Runs in the main thread, freezing up the UI until it completes. 
                        await numberManager.generateNumbers()
                    }
                }

        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("One", systemImage: "list.dash")
        }
        Text("Hello")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Two", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
    }

}

var isNumbersValid: Bool{
    numberManager.numbers != nil && numberManager.numbers?.count != 0
} }
```

### What I've tried...

I've tried a few things, but the only way that made it run in the background was changing the function as below. But I know that using Task.detached should be avoided unless it's absolutely necessary, and I didn't think this is the correct use-case.

```
    func generateNumbers() async  {
    Task.detached {
        var numbers = [Double]()
        numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
        await MainActor.run { [numbers] in
            self.numbers = numbers
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have flagged your class with `@MainActor` - so it is still executing on the main queue.  Remove that or, as you discovered, use structured concurrency to detatch the task from the main queue

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/70645342/13278922

Comment: Would simply getting rid of MainActor solve the issue? I tried it, and it's still running in the main thread. @Paulw11

Comment: Writing async on a function doesn’t make it leave the thread. You need a continuation and you need to actually leave the thread somehow. Nothing in your code leaves the thread and tells concurrency when to return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing `async` on a function doesn’t make it leave the thread. You need a continuation and you need to actually leave the thread somehow.

Some ways you can leave the thread using `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {` or use `Task.detached`.

But the most important part is returning to the `main` thread or even more specific to the Actor's thread.

`DispatchQueue.main.async` is the "old" way of returning to the main thread it shouldn't be used with `async await`. Apple as provided `CheckedContinuation` and `UncheckedContinuation` for this purpose.

[Meet async/await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132) can elaborate some more.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConcurrentSampleView: View {
    //Solution
    @StateObject var vm: AsyncNumberManager = .init()
    //Just to create a project that can show both scenarios.
    //@StateObject var vm: NumberManager = .init()

    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            //Just to visualize the thread being released
            //If you use NumberManager the ProgressView won't appear
            //If you use AsyncNumberManager the ProgressView WILL appear
            if isLoading{
                ProgressView()
            }
            
            Text(vm.numbers == nil ? "nil" : "\(vm.numbers?.count.description ?? "")")
        }
        //.task is better for iOS 15+
        .onAppear() {
            Task{
                isLoading = true
                await vm.generateNumbers()
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ConcurrentSampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConcurrentSampleView()
    }
}

@MainActor
class AsyncNumberManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numbers: [Double]?
    
    func generateNumbers() async  {
        numbers = await concurrentGenerateNumbers()
    }
    
    private func concurrentGenerateNumbers() async -> [Double]  {
        typealias Cont = CheckedContinuation<[Double], Never>
        return await withCheckedContinuation { (cont: Cont) in
            // This is the asynchronous part, have the operation leave the current actor's thread.
            //Change the priority as needed
            //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskpriority
            Task.detached(priority: .utility){
                var numbers = [Double]()
                numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
                //This tells the function to return to the actor's thread
                cont.resume(returning: numbers)
            }
        }
    }
    //Or something like this it just depends on the true scenario
    private func concurrentGenerateNumbers2() async -> [Double]  {
        // This is the asynchronous part, have the operation leave the actor's thread
        //Change the priority as needed
            //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskpriority
        return await Task.detached(priority: .utility){
            var numbers = [Double]()
            numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
            return numbers
        }.value
        
    }
    
}
//Incorrect way of applying async/await. This doesn't actually leave the thread or mark when to return. Left here to highlight both scenarios in a reproducible example.
@MainActor
class NumberManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numbers: [Double]?
    
    func generateNumbers() async  {
        
        var numbers = [Double]()
        numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
        self.numbers = numbers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question - You can use structured concurrency to solve your problem.

Your problem occurs because you have use the `@MainActor` decorator on your class.  This means that it executes on the main queue.

You can either remove this decorator or, as you have found, use structured concurrency to explicitly create a detached task and the use a main queue task to provide your result.

Which approach you use depends on what else this class does.  If it does a lot of other work that needs to be on the main queue then `@MainActor` is probably a good approach.  If not then remove it.

Comment: Thank you, so I'm assuming that using a structured concurrency as I did IS the actual use-case in these scenarios. On a side note, I did try a fresh build without MainActor, but it still runs on the Main Thread. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't remove the `MainActor` decorator. Any changes to an observed property must be done on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

The `@MainActor` property wrapper is not (just) what makes your observable object run on the main thread. `@StateObject` is what's doing it. Which is logical, since changes to the object will update the UI.

Removing the `@MainActor` wrapper is not the solution, because any changes to `@Published` properties will have to be done on the main thread (since they update the UI). You also don't want to run `Task.detached`, at least not if the task is going to change any `@Published` property, for the same reason.

By marking your `generateNumbers` function as `async`, a method from the main thread can call it with `await` - which allows the task to suspend and not block the main thread. That's what makes it concurrent.

```
extension NumberManager {
    func loadNumbers() {
        // This task will run on the main thread
        Task {
            // `await` tells the Swift executor that this method can run in the background, 
            // and the main thread can continue doing other things while it waits for its result
            self.numbers = await self.generateNumbers()
        }
    }

    func generateNumbers() async -> [Double] {
        return (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) 
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var numberManager = NumberManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            VStack{
                DetailView(text: isNumbersValid ? "First number is: \(numberManager.numbers![0])" : nil)
            }
        }

        .onAppear { numberManager.loadNumbers() }
    }
}
```

A more complete `loadNumbers` method could also store a reference to the task allowing you to cancel or restart a running task. However nowadays we have the excellent [`.task(priority:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/task(priority:_:)) to do all of that for you. It manages the task's lifecycle automatically, which means less boilerplate code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var numberManager = NumberManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            VStack{
                DetailView(text: isNumbersValid ? "First number is: \(numberManager.numbers![0])" : nil)
            }
        }

        // generate numbers
        .task(.priority: .high) {
            numberManager.numbers = await numberManager.generateNumbers
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know this is the most succinct way to do expensive calculations on a background thread in Swift 5.7.