# Does await use main thread or cooperative thread pool?

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, swift-concurrency

I know that await does not directly spawn a new thread, but just tell the function to suspend so the system can utilize threads for other work. But when it comes to how / which thread the system will use to continue executing the awaited task / work is a bit unclear.

I'm testing this on Xcode 14, where I have 3 fetch versions. Upon running here are my observations

- ViewModel.fetch1: run on main thread
- ViewModel.fetch2: run on cooperative thread pool
- ContentView.fetch: run on main thread

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var string = ""
    
    func fetch1() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        self.string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
    
    func fetch2() async {
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        self.string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var string = ""
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                Task {
                    await vm.fetch1()
                }
                
                Task {
                    await vm.fetch2()
                }
                
                Task {
                    await fetch()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Fetch")
            }
            
            Text(string)
            Text(vm.string)
        }
    }
    
    private func fetch() async {
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        self.string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}
```

I know that using new async/await concurrency model, it's not wise to think about thread, but here I'm trying to make sure it does not run heavy work on the main thread.

For the `ContentView.fetch` and `ViewModel.fetch1` methods being executed on the main thread, it's understandable that Task inherits the actor context, and since I make unstructured `Task` in SwiftUI body  which is using main actor.

For the `ViewModel.fetch2` method, I mark it as `async`, and somehow Swift decides to use cooperative thread pool instead of "inheriting" main actor context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swfit: Trouble running async functions in background threads (concurrency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538764/swfit-trouble-running-async-functions-in-background-threads-concurrency)

Comment: @loremipsum I've read that, it does not answer my question

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Does await use main thread or cooperative thread pool?

The `await` doesn’t dictate the thread. It just introduces a suspension point in your code. It all comes down to what you are awaiting.

The issue is that [`Task { … }`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) “[r]uns the given ... operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task on behalf of the current actor.”

If you want it off the main actor, you should use [`Task.detached { … }`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/detached(priority:operation:)-3lvix).

---

That having been said, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init/) for `Data(contentsOf:)` says:

> Don't use this synchronous initializer to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

So, I would avoid `Data(contentsOf:)` for anything other than reading small files from your local file system. Instead, use `URLSession`:

```swift
func fetch3() async throws -> String {
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
}
```

That completely avoids the problem of needing to worry about which actor you run it from. It also offers cancelation capabilities and a number of other benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob. I use `Data(contentsOf:)` here to understand how it will possibly block the main thread. What I find unclear is which main thread vs thread pool the system will use to execute the awaited task

Comment: Don’t use the main actor if you have something slow and synchronous that you don’t want it blocking the main thread. So, that means detached tasks, or your own actors.