# ProgressView not updating during long task

Tags: swiftui

I am running a long `Task` and want to present progress updates to the user in the main view of my iOS (iPad) app. The code below does not update during the task but only at the end of it.

The view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

 var body: some View {
  HStack {
   Button("Start") { viewModel.go() }
   ProgressView("Counting...", value: viewModel.progress, total: 1.0)
  }
 }
}
```

The view model:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
 @Published var progress = 0.0

 func go() {
  Task { @MainActor in
   let c = 1...10
   for n in c {
    progress = Double(n) / 10.0
    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538764/trouble-running-async-functions-in-background-threads-concurrency/73542522#73542522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of objectWillChange will solve the problem. objectWillChange is an observable object's publisher that emits before the object has changed. By calling send() on this publisher, we are manually notifying any subscribers  that the object is about to change

```
      import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Start") {
                viewModel.go()
            }
            .padding()

            ProgressView("Counting...", value: viewModel.progress, total: 1.0)
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progress = 0.0

    func go() {
        Task {
            for n in 1...10 {
                await MainActor.run {
                    self.progress = Double(n) / 10.0
                }
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix GCD and async/await, async/await replaces GCD

Answer (score -1):

In SwiftUI the `View` protocol is the view model already you don't need a class. Also it's `.task` not `Task`, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var progress: Progress?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(progress != nil ? "Stop" : "Start") {
                 progress = Progress()
            }
            if let progress {
                ProgressView(progress)
            }
        }
        .task(id: progress) {
            if progress == nil { return }
            result = await go(progress)
            progress = nil
        }
     }
}
```