# Updating a View in a loop

Tags: swift, loops, swiftui, state

I am trying to create some feedback when iterating through a directory. I find that the text field doesn’t update until right at the end.

Here is a test script which has the same problem:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var thing: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            VStack {
                Text(String(thing))
                Button("Test") {
                    for i in 1 ... 1000000 {
                        thing = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again the text field doesn’t update until the loop is completed. I presume that all updates occur when the code has completed.

How can I update the view continually?

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't have any suspension points -- it just runs until finished. I'm guessing your real-world application is more complicated than this, but the gist is that at some point you have to cede control back to the main thread/run loop if you want it to run updates. Otherwise, your app will just "hang"

Comment: Use `await async` + `sleep`?

Comment: @ElTomato I’m listening …

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77937586/progressview-not-updating-during-long-task

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var thing: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text(thing, format: .number)
                Button("Test") {
                    thing = 1
                }
                .task(id: thing) {
                    if thing == 0 { return }
                    if thing > 10000 { return }
                    do {
                        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                        thing += 1
                    catch {
                        thing = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```